# Get the most common comma count, its line count and total line count

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the following script to get the counts of commas in files.

```
ls | select -First 10 |
% { 
    $_.FullName;
    cat $_ | Select-String `, -AllMatches | 
    Select-Object LineNumber, @{ n = "Count"; e = { $_.Matches.Count }} |
    Group-Object Count
}
```

The script returns the following rows for each file. How do I get the most common comma counts for each file? As for the following example, I will need to pass the most comma count *77*, the line count *108* and total lines (*108 + 8 +5 = 121*) to another program.

```
File1.txt

Count Name                      Group                                                                             
----- ----                      -----                                                                             
  108 77                        {@{LineNumber=1; Count=77}, @{LineNumber=2; Count=77}, @{LineNumber=3; Count=77...
    8 78                        {@{LineNumber=7; Count=78}, @{LineNumber=15; Count=78}, @{LineNumber=22; Count=...
    5 79                        {@{LineNumber=16; Count=79}, @{LineNumber=32; Count=79}, @{LineNumber=37; Count...

File2.txt
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, packaging the relevant pieces of data into a custom object for each file:

```
ls | select -First 10 |
% { 
    $numLines = 0
    $grouped = cat $_ `
               |%{ $numLines++; $_ }  `
               | Select-String ',' -AllMatches `
               | Select-Object LineNumber, @{ n = "Count"; e = { $_.Matches.Count }} `
               | Group-Object Count `
               | sort Count -Desc

    [PsCustomObject] @{
         File = $_.FullName
         TopCommaCount = [int] $grouped[0].Name
         TopCommaCountLines = [int] $grouped[0].Count
         TotalLines = $numLines
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, you should sort the output of Group by Count (descending) and select the first one:

```
ls | select -First 10 |
% { 
    $_.FullName;
    cat $_ | Select-String `, -AllMatches | 
    Select-Object LineNumber, @{ n = "Count"; e = { $_.Matches.Count }} |
    Group-Object Count | Sort Count -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
}
```

To measure the number of lines with a comma:

```
ls | select -First 10 |
% { 
    $_.FullName;
    cat $_ | Select-String `, -AllMatches | 
    Select-Object LineNumber, @{ n = "Count"; e = { $_.Matches.Count }} |
    Measure-Object Count
}
```

Comment: Is it a way to get the total lines for each file?